# Is there a way to test whether an array has been created?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a code like

```
 #include <iostream>



int main() {


    int** array = new int*[2];
    int row1;
    int row2;
    int answer;


    std::cout << "Type 1 to create the 2d array: ";
    std::cin >> answer;



    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (answer == 1) {
    array[0] = new int[0];
    array[1] = new int[0];


    std::cout << "Fill the first array row: ";

    std::cin >> row1;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Fill the second row: ";

    std::cin >> row2;

    array[0][0] = row1;
    array[1][0] = row2;
}

    else 
{
    std::cout << "No arrays created";
}


// Here I test if the array[0][0] was created but when the answer is not 1,but 2 
// it should ignore the if-statement at the bottom but it still execute's it 
// and my debugger get an application error
// So is there an other way to test if an array was created ,no vectors.
// I have to do it with arrays :P

    if (array[0][0] > 0)
{

    std::cout << "1." << array[0][0] << "    2." << array[1][0] << std::endl;

}


    return 0;

}
```

What should I use instead of the `(array[0][0] > 0)`

If i use 2 as answer the program still executes the bottom if-statement and  the debugger get an application error , but when the answer is 1 everything is fine . Why it still executes the bottom if-statement ?

I updated the code

Comment: Please include a code snippet demonstrating what you mean. "Array" can mean several things in C++ (such as C style array or std::array).

Comment: what do you mean by creation?

Comment: What do you mean? Difference between static and dynamic arrays. Use Vectors/List anyway.

Comment: Vote to reopen, code example is sufficient to show the intent. (The answer will be "use std::vector, but if you insist on a hand-rolled solution it's `int* array = nullptr; /******/ if (array) { }` )

Comment: You should avoid `new`, `delete` and owning raw pointers completely. In this case, use a `vector<int>`. C++ is not C, do not start by learning the C-way, Most of the things that are 'best practices' for C, is anti-patterns for C++. Owning raw pointers would be a prime example, consider it a cardinal sin.

Comment: Hmm ok , but my execise is to create an program with dynamic arrays. Now I want to create an dynamic 2d-array ,if the demanded input creates an array , I want to test if an array was created , when not then it just should say "array not created".

Comment: @Yunus: but a `vector` *is* a dynamic array, that is exactly what it is, plus with RAII enabled

Comment: @sp2danny Ah okay I understand , thank you

Answer (score 3):

OK, I dont know if I understand your question but it depends of the structure:

- Memory:

  ```
  int *array = 0; //=nullptr
  if (array==0) or if (array==nullptr)
  ```
- Vector:

  ```
  vector<Obj> v;
  if (v.empty())
  ```
- List:

  ```
  list<Obj> l;
  if (l.empty())
  ```

  And it depends of the structure.

Note: When you create a structure directly, no a pointer, it is created automatly

```
  vector<Obj> a; //Called to the constructor

  vector<Obj>* a = 0; // It is not created check with if(!a)
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize `array` to `nullptr`.

Comment: Yes, completly true.

Comment: Why use `vector:size` and `list::size`? There are `vector::empty` and `list::empty`.

Comment: Also, the very last part is wrong. You cannot check whether `vector<Obj>*a;` was created using `if (!a)`. `a` is uninitialized and can contain some garbage value.

Comment: @lisyarus yes, I wrote this post very fast, thanks for notify me, changed!